# Given an algebraic group $G$ is $G^0$ (connected component including the identity) unique?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I have two basic questions regarding connected components including the identity of algebraic groups.

1. Given an algebraic group $G$ is $G^0$ (connected component including the identity) unique?
2. Let $H$ be an algebraic subgroup of $G$. Does it then always follow that $H^0$ is contained in $G^0$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What would it possibly mean that the connected component of the identity is not unique?

Comment: You should probably review in a textbook on topology the basics of connectedness!

Comment: To spell it out, the answer to both questions is **yes**, $G^0$ is **the** connected component of $G$ containing the identity (you basically said it yourself). If $H\subseteq G$, then also $H^0\subseteq G$ and $H^0$ is connected, so it must be contained in a connected component of $G$. Since $H^0$ also contains the identity, we must have $H^0\subseteq G^0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I was getting some very basic things mixed up in my head.